# Plotting against a set of key and values in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to read data from a file and then build a dictionary out of the file. With this dictionary, I want to plot a graph with the keys of the dictionary as the X graph and the values of the dictionary as the markup values. However, the key values are strings and I just need to label them. I tried the following code, which throws an error stating that the key value is a string.

```
The data from the data.txt file reads as follows:
new:10,not new:30,10:40,a:5.0

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fileopen=open("data.txt", "r")
for a in fileopen.readlines():
b= a.split(",")
fileopen.close()
newdict={}
for c in b:
 newdict.update({c.rstrip("\',\",").split(":")[0]:eval(c.rstrip("\',\",").split(":")[1])})


plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=80)
x=[i for i in newdict]
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,4,1, endpoint=True))
y=[newdict[j] for j in newdict]
plt.plot(y, color="blue", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-")
plt.show()
```

And this is the error that I get on my console.

```
File "C:\Users\Annakoppad\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 474, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: a
```

I am unable to proceed further, can someone help in this regard?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `csv` if this is truly csv data. `csv.DictReader` might be able to help you. Ideally key names aren't mixed through the data, but would be defined positionally based on the first row, with rows like:

```
new,not new,10,a
10,30,40,5.0
```

if you don't want to put keys in the csv at all, you could define a sequence of the key names:

```
keys=("new","not new",10,"a")
```

Remember that when working with csv (and also readlines), each value is read as a string, so if rows contain different data types you'll have to convert the individual keys to get ints or floats.

ref: csv https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.DictReader